# Python: pyspark sorting orders

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

In pyspark data frame, I used data brick to read csv.bz2 file from AWS:

```
data = sqlContext.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("header", "false").option("delimiter" , "\t").option("mode", "PERMISSIVE").option("inferSchema", "true").load("s3n://myPath/Data.csv.bz2")
```

I did the following transformation:

```
data_sort = data.sort(data.Last_Name, data.First_Name)
```

Then for the output Last_Name, I got the order like below:

```
ABC, ...
BROWN, ...
GREEN, ...
WATER, ...
A, ...
```

Why would `A` show up last? Shouldn't it be before `ABC`? Am I missing anything there?

Comment: Can you show your code? Is it really `A` with nothing in-front of it? Could it be a different [Unicode character](http://unicode.org/cldr/utility/confusables.jsp?a=A&r=None)?

Comment: The above is my code. data is a spark data frame, read from a csv.bz2 file.

Comment: What creates `csv.bz2`? Is that available?

Comment: When I run this coding using `data = sc.parallelize([["ABC","a"],["BROWN","b"],["Green","g"],["Water","w"],["A","a"]]).toDF(["Last_Name","First_Name"])` and then I run the sort code provided by @Edamame, it sorts properly with `A` at the beginning. Please provide more data, more information, or more code. Your problem is not currently reproducible.

Comment: I am using data brick to read the csv.bz2 file from AWS (added in the question). Could that be a problem?